# How to select top n columns from list of dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have time-series data collected based on a weekly basis. I need to split given time series data into the specific year and find out top n columns for each sub dataframe. To do so, I tried to use `nlargest` but not getting the expected sub dataframe after filtering out the columns based on row sum. Can anyone point me out what would be correct way to do this? Any idea?

**my current attempt**:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the data
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jerry-shad/cca5393505d9c67ebca05bee3f40170c/raw/9792cf2a70e2cddbfd4f9a4529d25b42aad9421d/mydat.csv'
df_ = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
# df_.set_index('weekly', inplace=True)
df_['year'] = df_['weekly'].dt.year
df_['week'] = df_['weekly'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('int')
df_.columns = df_.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
df_.drop('weekly', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_new = df_.set_index(['year','week'])

for n, g in df_new.groupby(level=0):
    for k in g:
        colsum = g.apply(lambda x: x.sum()).nlargest(4)
```

but it is not right to me because I need to reduce sub-dataframe by selecting top n columns. Not I have little unusual output that is unlikely to be correctly filtered out. Any idea to make this right?

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: @ScottBoston I don't have concrete desired output, but each sub dataframe should be reduced by selecting its top n columns.

Comment: @ScottBoston I think you misunderstood me. In desired output, list of countries should be less, for example, `['CANADA','HGKONG', 'MEXICO','TAIWAN']`. how should we do it?  for instance, `ARGENT`, `RUSSIA`, `NZEAL` should be filtered out.

Comment: by year, what if you have four different country for each year?  You wat a dataframe with eight columns?

Comment: @ScottBoston that's possible, right? in this case, that's fine because different countries might be in a different years. I still want 52 weeks window but fewer countries. current attempt is also interesting to me but keep 52 weeks with top n countries. Is that doable?

Comment: @ScottBoston what if list of countries in 2018 is not overlapped or partially overlap with 2019, how should we do it? can we make sub-dataframe so the list of columns for each sub-dataframe might be same or different, but not mixing up that they share same column list. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you need to decide your desired output?  Maybe a dictionary with key of years for each top 4 countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a dictionary of dataframes by year:

```
d = {}
for g, n in df_new.groupby(level=0):
    d[g] = n.loc[:,n.sum().rank(ascending=False,method='min')<5]
    
print(d[2018])
print(d[2019])
```

Still pretty unsure what exactly you want:

```
df_new.loc[:,(df_new.groupby(level=0).sum().rank(axis=1, ascending=False)<5).any()]
```

Output:

```
           HGKONG   JAPAN  KORREP  MEXICO  TAIWAN
year week                                        
2018 1      864.0  1850.0  2126.0   572.0   852.0
     2     2366.0  4451.0  3714.0  1668.0  1071.0
     3     2189.0  5521.0  4301.0  1792.0   958.0
     4     2470.0  4057.0  3589.0  2238.0  1171.0
     5     2510.0  4971.0  4039.0  1751.0   927.0
...           ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2019 48    1684.0  4498.0  4961.0  1866.0  1407.0
     49    1562.0  4484.0  4557.0  1955.0  1795.0
     50    1170.0  4643.0  3821.0  2312.0  1156.0
     51     987.0  3870.0  3231.0  1468.0  1148.0
     52     486.0  3946.0  3632.0  1344.0   893.0

[105 rows x 5 columns]
```

IIUC, you can try something like this:

```
(df_new.reindex(df_new.assign(total=df_new.sum(axis=1))
                      .groupby(level=0, group_keys=False)['total']
                      .nlargest(4).index)
```

Output:

```
           ARGENT  AUSTRAL  CANADA   CHINA  EUROPEAN  HGKONG    JAPAN   KORREP  MEXICO  NZEAL  RUSSIA  TAIWAN  UKING
year week                                                                                                           
2018 40       0.0      0.0  1479.0   117.0     235.0  2356.0   6142.0   5590.0  2243.0    0.0     0.0  1552.0    0.0
     51       0.0      0.0  1148.0   104.0      81.0  1962.0   8079.0   4651.0  2083.0    0.0     0.0  1462.0    0.0
     28       0.0      0.0  1310.0    48.0     177.0  1180.0   6306.0   5928.0  2047.0    0.0     0.0  1599.0    0.0
     30       0.0      0.0  1168.0   271.0       5.0  1219.0   7194.0   4947.0  1822.0    0.0     0.0  1440.0    0.0
2019 6        0.0      0.0  5359.0   609.0     175.0  5437.0  22828.0  18415.0  9938.0    0.0     0.0  4815.0   16.0
     45       0.0      0.0   809.0  1134.0    2004.0  3031.0   8611.0   6079.0  3187.0    0.0     0.0  1320.0    0.0
     17       0.0      0.0  1344.0    89.0       2.0  1754.0   6311.0   8152.0  3029.0    0.0     0.0  2031.0    0.0
     23       0.0      0.0  1079.0   171.0     340.0  1651.0   6661.0   5322.0  1779.0    0.0     0.0  1235.0    1.0
```